# Indices of all the overlapping patterns using Pattern & Matcher

Tags: java, pattern-matching

How do I get all the indices(including overlapping) of the string where a pattern is matching.
I have this poc code.

```
public static void main(){
    String input = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("aaa");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    List<Integer> all = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        all.add(matcher.start());
    }
    System.out.println(all);
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27]
```

It does not consider overlapping patterns.
All the matching indices should be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, .....27]
```

I know it is easily doable by KMP, but 
**Can we do it using Pattern and Matcher?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your regex so that the entire expression is within a lookahead, i.e. change `"aaa"` to `"(?=aaa)"`. This way, the matcher will find overlapping matches, although the matches are not *really* overlapping, as the actual match will be empty. You can still use groups in the lookahead, though. As a more complex example ([Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q3CKu8/1)):

```
String input = "abab1ab2ab3bcaab4ab5ab6";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=((?:ab.){2}))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.start() + " " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Starting indices and groups are:

```
2 ab1ab2
5 ab2ab3
14 ab4ab5
17 ab5ab6
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you @tobias_k. Any good source to learn and experiment with regex more?

Comment: @impossible There are online regex testers that are great for experimenting, as those will often also provide a detailed breakdown of the regex parts. See the link in my updated answer.

Comment: That is helpful. Thank you!